# Push rejected to <App>, specify NodeJS

Tags: json, nodejs, imagen, push-notification, heroku

Estoy tratando de subir una aplicación a Heroku con 19 imágenes, puedo empujar el git antes de 17, al momento de subir la imagen 18, recibo error al subir el código que dice así (aethos es mi aplicacion):

```
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! react-redux-router@1.0.0 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack/prod.config.js --progress --display-error-details --color`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the react-redux-router@1.0.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.9Xwed/_logs/2019-11-27T21_14_37_874Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! react-redux-router@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `npm run build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the react-redux-router@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.9Xwed/_logs/2019-11-27T21_14_37_891Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to aethos.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/aethos.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/aethos.git'
```

intente subir las imagenes una por una pero mismo error, tambien segui los links dentro del codigo pero aun especificando las versiones de npm y node, no hubo cambio. Eso o no supe hacerlo correctamente

Comment: Normalmente el error se muestra mas arriba de `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE`, revisa con detenimiento todo lo que te imprima la consola

Comment: Como comenta @RimuruTempest, trata de colocar lo que falta del error. Por otra parte, a tu archivo `package.json` le hace falta el valor de `engines`, tal como lo especifica la [documentación](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version) de `heroku`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras eso lo hace automáticamente heroku, sino especificas unas versión de Node o de NPM, heroku automáticamente instala la versiones mas estables de node y npm. Pero no esta demás agregarlos en caso de que quieras instalar un versión específica de cada uno.